# Android: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=image/* }

Tags: android, imageview

I have one `ImageView` in my layout file. I just want to load an image in the `ImageView` when I open my app.

But what happens is that when I open my app it occurs an error message

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT cat=[android.intent.category.OPENABLE] typ=image/* }
```

Here is the code

```
ImageView mImageView;
    private static final int REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_viewer_main);

        mImageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        if(requestCode==REQUEST_OPEN_RESULT_CODE && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri uri=null;
            if(resultData!=null){
                uri=resultData.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap=getBitmapFromUri(uri);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException{
        ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor=getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor=parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        parcelFileDescriptor.close();
        return bitmap;

    }
```

Comment: Which API Level you are using?

Comment: if device version is greater then `Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT` then use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT ` otherwise  use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT `

Comment: API 18
minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: ok see my previous comment.

Comment: perfect. It is working now. Thank you very much ρяσѕρєя K